# How to invalidate other session in java servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have a usecase like below:
User A is with user role and login successfully on application
User B is with admin role and login successfully on application

While User B manage and monitor the application. He want to kick off User A out of the application.

I know that only kick off User A by invalidating User A session.

Question: How can User B invalidate User A session with best solution?